# When sending out press releases, do you include a cover letter?

Tags: press-release

I'm preparing a book release for a book I publish via CreateSpace, and being a noob I wonder if press releases normally go out with cover letters, or just stuffed in an envelope?

I'm using snail mail to send to newspaper book editors, since I've found it easier to come up with mailing addresses as opposed to email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never put a cover letter on a press release.

There are services out there that will send a press release to hundreds of media outlets for you for a couple of hundred dollars. I've got responses from press releases I've sent out this way and I've seen my press releases show up on web sites, so at least some of these are not scams. :-)

Comment: That's good to hear!  I'm sending out press releases myself to 92 of the biggest newspapers in the US, and I've been considering using one of those services, too.  I did not want to write a cover letter, that's for sure!  Except I did include one to one books editor because it is the newspaper of the city where my author lives, and perhaps they would like the "local author" angle.